# JavaScript to pass todays date onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view (**MVC5**, C#) with a drop down. When the user selects a new status for an order, from the dropddown I want to update the CurrentStatusDate EditFor box.  I am very close but no cigar yet.  Here is what I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("[name='CheckStatus']").change(function () {

        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd;
        }

        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm;
        }

        today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
        $("CurrentStatsDate").val($(today).val());      
  });
});
```

This is the line, I believe I am struggling to get the correct syntax for . . .

```
 $("CurrentStatsDate").val($(today).val());
```

I have added my view code for CurrentStatusDate Object

```
   <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentStatusDate, (string)"Current Status Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrentStatusDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly",  @Value = ViewBag.ThisDay } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurrentStatusDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is `"CurrentStatsDate"`? A tag?

Comment: you're confused about when to use jQuery. `$("CurrentStatsDate").val(today.toString());` should be fine... as long as that selector passes, which it won't because it doesn't include a class or id part, you'll need something like `$(".CurrentStatsDate")`, assuming `CurrentStatsDate` is an id of an element

Comment: @Teemu  "CurrentStatusDate" is the id for the htm.EditFor box, which I just now added to my original question

Comment: you just have a typo. ```$("CurrentStatsDate")``` needs to be ```$("#CurrentStatusDate")```

Comment: If it's an id, then use the id selector instead of the tag selector ...

Comment: @Teemu - Ok.  So, I am not too familiar with this. But I googled for more info and found this to start.  var x = document.getElementById("CurrentDateStatus");
            x = today;   But I am still having issues.  I think my x = today; is the issue?

Comment: @ry4nolson - thanks for pointing out the typo. I had corrected that and it still did not work.  I am now trying Id Selector as Teemu suggested to see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your selector is missing the `#` and also has a typo.

`$("CurrentStatsDate")` should be `$("#CurrentStatusDate")`

Also, `$(today).val()` is going to fail. `today` is being set to a string on the previous line. so you can just use `$("#CurrentStatusDate").val(today)`

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!!